# Using timeline google chart api with php - DataTable initialization

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, google-visualization

I am trying to implement the timeline google `chart` 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

but using `date format` is creating some errors in generating the `chart`.
All dates are set default to `dec 31 1969`.
I know that I am passing a wrong format of date. How can I fix this.

tried implementing in two ways :

```
$table['cols'] = array(
        array('id' => 'Role', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('id' => 'Name', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('id' => 'Start', 'type' => 'date'),
        array('id' => 'End', 'type' => 'date')
    );
```

One way:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['FirstName']); /*mysql and mysqli security please ignore */
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['FirstName']);
$temp[] = array('v' =>  date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['HireDate'])); /*tried without date function also*/
$temp[] = array('v' =>  date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['ExpectedEndDate']));
$rows[] = $temp;
```

Other way:

```
$temp[] = $row['FirstName'];
$temp[] = $row['FirstName'];
$temp[] =date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['HireDate']); 
$temp[] =date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['ExpectedEndDate']);
$rows[] = $temp;
```

and then storing it into table and converting it into `json`.

`$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);`

storing it as javascript variable using google visualization `DataTable` as follows:

```
 var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable;?>);
```

But because of date format conflict (I think) the chart is not being outputted

On inspecting the final generated output the variable is storing the value as :

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"id":"Role","type":"string"},{"id":"Name","type":"string"},{"id":"Start","type":"date"},{"id":"End","type":"date"}],"rows":[[{"v":"bob"},{"v":"bob"},{"v":"Wed Dec 31 1969 16:33:28 -0800"},{"v":"Wed Dec 31 1969 16:33:33 -0800"}],[{"v":"alan"},{"v":"alan"},{"v":"Wed Dec 31 1969 16:33:28 -0800"},{"v":"Wed Dec 31 1969 16:33:33 -0800"}]]});
```

Can anyone suggest how to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes I am getting 
`Cannot read property '2' of undefined `
it being `google chart` huge `javascript` am unable to localize the error. but all I can say it is from date (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
$temp[] = array('v' =>  date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['HireDate']));
```

Dates must be input in a very specific string-format: `"Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)"`, where `month` is the zero-based index for the month, and everything after `month` is optional (defaults are 1 for `day` and 0 for everything else).  To input your date in this format, you should do something like this:

```
$date = date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$row['HireDate']));
$year = (int) date_format($date, 'Y');
$month = ((int) date_format($date, 'm')) - 1; // adjust to javascript's 0-indexed months
$day  = (int) date_format($date, 'd');
$hours = (int) date_format($date, 'H');
$minutes = (int) date_format($date, 'i');
$seconds = (int) date_format($date, 's');

$temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds");
```