# Assign columns to a google chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a google chart pulling data from a mysql database.
If I pass the returned array (arr) directly to DataTable(), it works:

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(arr);
var options = {}; // assign some options
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Now I'd like to add some columns prior to assigning the array. This results in an error.
I have googled many examples (E.g. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947898/redraw-google-chart-based-on-user-input-via-ajax-request/38955110#38955110) but can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);    
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
   
// Uncaught (in promise) Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array
var rows = JSON.parse(arr);
dataTable.addRows(rows);

// This doesn't work either: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array
dataTable.addRows(arr);

var options = {}; // assign some options
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the columns in PHP and it works now.

like this

```
$table['cols'] = array(...)
```

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706810/using-timeline-google-chart-api-with-php-datatable-initialization)